# Django custom testrunner

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

i try to override DJango 1.6 custom testrunner, i want to override the teardown_database and teardown_test methods to avoid deletion of test data (i want to look inside the db...):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner
from django.conf import settings

class KeepDBTestRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):

    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        pass

    def teardown_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        pass
```

But when i run the manage.py test with testrunner with --testrunner option i get:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'
...
Ran 230 tests in 1.364s
```

Without custom testrunner it run only the 3 test that i have wrote.

What's wrong with my custom testrunner, i override a simple method but seems that system run another test set....

Thanks.

Comment: Do you specify the app name while executing `test` command?

Comment: If i specify the app name it execute the correct test set (3 tests..), the database is created correctly, but without data...

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is by pointing Django at your custom test runner class by setting the `TEST_RUNNER` variable in `settings.py`

e.g.

`TEST_RUNNER = 'mymodule.KeepDBTestRunner'`

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEST_RUNNER